# How to reset a struct entry in C

Tags: c, struct

I have an array of structs.  It's declared like this:

```
tableEntry [MAXSCOPE][MAXSIZE];
```

When the structs are created, C automatically initializes all the members to either 0 or null.

Let's say that I have given some values to the struct members of tableEntry[1][0], tableEntry[1][1], and tableEntry[1][2].

Now I want to reinitialize all struct members in tableEntry[1][x], where x can be any number from 0 up to MAXSIZE.  How would I do that?

Essentially, I want to "delete" those structs.  Later I might want to write to those structs and I don't want my new data to be contaminated by any old data that's already there, that's why I want to get rid of all the old data and reinitialize it like when it's first created.

Comment: C doesn't initialise anything for you.

Comment: @Pod, C does initialize them to zero if they're 'global' (i.e external linkage)

Answer (score 4):

No, C only automatically initializes all the members to 0 when your variable has static storage, otherwise you have to write:

```
struct TableEntry tableEntry [MAXSCOPE][MAXSIZE] = {0};
```

If your `tableEntry` is a global variable or declared `static` inside a function, then you don't need the `= {0}` part.

Then you can use `memset` to reinitialize some of the entries afterwards:

```
memset(tableEntry[1], 0, sizeof(struct TableEntry) * MAXSIZE);
```

will reinitialize `tableEntry[1][0] ... tableEntry[1][MAXSIZE - 1]` to `0`.

Comment: C **does** guarantee zero-initialization of variables with static lifetime (global and static variables).

Comment: He's very likely using global storage, though, but I can't be sure. Either way, we're all just trying to help the OP sort out his troubles.

Comment: next time, please explain the downvote(s) so that I can improve, thx!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but all bytes 0 may or may not represent zero for some types.  In particular, floating point and pointer values can have 0 as not all bytes 0.

Comment: @Gregory: because the C standard allows this. There are systems where memory location `0` has useful code. On such systems, `NULL` is not all bits `0`. Similarly, there are floating point representations where all bits 0 is not floating-point 0.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
memset( &tableEntry1[1][x], 0, sizeof(tableEntry1[0][0]) );
```

Incidentally, the maximum value of x is MAXSIZE-1, not MAXSIZE.

Comment: memset all bits to 0. This is not guaranteed to be the same as assigning zero, for example for floating point or pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [memset](http://man.cx/memset%283posix%29) to set all bits to zero.

```
#include <string.h>

    memset(&tableEntry[1][0], 0, sizeof tableEntry[1][0]);
    memset(&tableEntry[1][1], 0, sizeof tableEntry[1][1]);
    memset(&tableEntry[1][2], 0, sizeof tableEntry[1][2]);

    /* if the elements are contiguous in memory,
     * you can set more than 1 in a single statement */
    memset(&tableEntry[1][0], 0, 3 * sizeof tableEntry[1][0]); /* zeroes ...[1][0], [1][1], and [1][2] */

    /* to set all of a sub array */
    memset(tableEntry[1], 0, sizeof tableEntry[1]);
```

Maybe setting all bits to 0 might not be what you want. If that's the case, you need to "delete" the elements one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset a whole row, ignore these people with `for` loops. You can do a row in one call to `memset()`, because rows are consecutive in memory:

```
memset(&tableEntry[1][0], 0, sizeof(tableEntry[0]));
```

`sizeof(tableEntry[0])` will be `MAXSIZE * sizeof(type)`, so this will reset all the elements, which, being the bottom level of an array, have to be contiguous in memory. (Anyone saying otherwise is arguing academics, because the OP has posted previous questions about this, and I believe `tableEntry` is just a two-dimensional array allocated on the stack.)

Comment: `memset(tableEntry[1], 0, sizeof tableEntry[1])` is completely equivalent, and looks a bit better to my eye anyway.

Comment: I agree that `&tableEntry[1][0]` is a bit hard on the eyes, and I would normally use the shorter version (I don't know why I used the longer version here), but I personally prefer to always use parentheses around my `sizeof` just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `memset` suggestions, I offer this:

```
/* Global variables are initialized to zero by compiler. */
struct foo TableEntry[MAXSCOPE][MAXSIZE];
struct foo zero;

/* Initialize yourself. */
for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
    TableEntry[1][i] = zero;
```

If you wish to optimize, you can in your build script see if `memset` does the same thing as assigning the `zero` struct and optionally use `memset` instead. You might want to profile things to see if it matters, though.

Comment: "does the same thing as **assing** the `zero` struct" While I understand your abbreviation, it's still really funny.

Comment: If it's not too embarrassing for you, I'm totally leaving the comment there.

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

All the answers with `memset` don't do the Right Thing always.  This is because all-bits-zero may not represent zero for floating-point numbers and pointers.  You can do this though:

```
static struct T zeroed; /* static, therefore every member
                           is initialized to an appropriate
                           'zero' value */
size_t i;
for (i=0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
    tableEntry[1][i] = zeroed;
```

Comment: NULL pointer is zero. And at least in IEEE floating point numbers, zero value is represented by all bits zero. Static storage may or may not be initialized to zero, depending on compiler options. But if it is initialized, that is done by filling the memory with zero bytes.

Comment: @PauliL: If you assign the value 0 to a pointer (p=0;) then the pointer is effectively set to NULL. But the representation of a NULL-pointer is not required to be all bits 0. In fact I had an old DOS compiler where a NULL pointer was all bits 1.